# Hiding an element using jQuery; which method should I use and why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the difference between these two methods?

```
$("div span").hide();

$("div > span").hide();
```

Any impact on performance?

Comment: Is this jQuery or what framework are you using?

Comment: This really looks like jQuery. ;)

Comment: Just an idea, should i use child parent selection or typical other one, may be css or jquery. does not matter.

Comment: It's obviously jQuery, look at the tags.

Comment: @Rikudo jquery tags were added after the fact...

Comment: The value of this question is somewhat diminished, since you won't be using two type selectors ( `div` and `span` ) in such a manner anyway. Usually, you have ID/class selectors like so: `$('#foo > .bar')`, or `$('.bar', foo)`. Then we can talk about performance...

Answer (score 12):

The first will hide all `<span>`s found anywhere under the `<div>`. The second will only hide `<span>`s that are immediate children of the `<div>`.

[jQuery child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: Both are equally fast. But the second one will not work on `<div><p><span>THIS SPAN</span></p></div>`, while the first one will.

Comment: I can't speak definitively on that. If I had to guess, I would think the child-selector would be faster since the search scope is narrower (only immediate children). If you only need immediate children, I would use the second one anyway to avoid accidentally selecting `<span>`s that are farther down the tree.

Comment: @RikudoSennin far from it. They are not both equally fast.

Comment: Anyone have a jsperf for the two?

Comment: `>` is a little faster: http://jsperf.com/selector-child. Second run it's the opposite though. This is on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

On the performance aspect, it may depend upon the exact HTML, but I found the `div > span` selector to be about 30% faster in this [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-performance/2).  That may be because it only has to look in the children of each div rather than through the whole DOM.

But, it's probably not enough of a speed difference to matter in most cases.